# How to get the lastest commit from branch A that was the leave when branch B was merged into A?

Tags: git, github

I need to checkout a version of my project locally so I can work on features that existed before branch B was merged into A, so I need to work with latest commit from A just before B was merged.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Suppose we have commit 1 on the branch A and on branch B we have commit 2,3,4,5...n. As the branch wasn't merged until som time later, some other pr were merged into A, so we have now on A commits 1,n+1,...Y.

Now we will merge branch B into A and keep the work going until some months later.

First question is: Will A stays as 1,n+1,...Y,2,3,4,5...n after the merge?

Main question: How can I get commit 1 if I don't now it's id or commit message?

Comment: In general, instead of editing a question to make a new question, you should just post a whole new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out any historical commit, as a *detached HEAD*.  This uses a special mode in Git, one where you *view* a commit but normally don't actually do any *new* work.

To do this, find the commit's raw hash ID, or use any Git *tag*, which is mostly a way of putting a human-readable name in to say *this name shall, from now until the true death of this project, mean hash ID _____* (fill in the blank).  Use this hash ID or human-readable name as an argument to `git checkout` or `git switch`.  If you're using a raw hash ID, you can abbreviate as long as it is not ambiguous, but the easy way to get it right—raw hash IDs are very unfriendly to humans, who always<sup>1</sup> get them wrong—is to cut-and-paste the hash ID from some `git log` output for instance:

```
git checkout 86ab15cb154862b6fa5cc646dac27532f881e1fb
```

When you are working with a Git repository, you normally work with one where Git has prepared a *working tree* or *work-tree* area for you.  This `git checkout` fills in your work-tree from the commit you specify, which becomes the current commit.

(If you have Git 2.23 or later, you may wish to use `git switch` instead of `git checkout` here.  It does exactly the same thing, for this case.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Insert distorted Gilbert-&-Sullivan routine here.  "What, never?  No, always!" or something like that.

---

#### What detached HEAD vs non-detached (attached) HEAD mode is all about

In normal everyday Git usage, you use something like:

```
git checkout master        # or git switch master
```

or:

```
git checkout develop       # or git switch develop
```

where you supply a *branch name*.  The branch name selects a commit (by its hash ID as always) and Git fills in your work-tree from that commit, but instead of *just* picking a commit, this also tells Git: *... and when I make my **next** commit, add it to the branch I am using.*

When you use:

```
git checkout <raw hash ID>
```

you're still selecting a commit, but promising Git that if you do make later commits, they're all temporary and can all be thrown away later.  So you can *use* the work-tree files all you like, for viewing or compiling or whatever, but you don't normally actually *make* any new commits.

(If you *do* make new commits in this mode, you get an opportunity to tell Git *oh, and keep these around now*, as long as you do it reasonably quickly—within a month or so, by default—of re-attaching `HEAD` to a branch, or switching to another commit.  Git also uses this detached HEAD mode internally for some of its own operations, such as doing `git rebase`.)

Comment: This is a large answer, thank you for the effort, but it doesn't answer my question, I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: It answers the question you actually asked. :-) The one you intended to ask is trickier because you have described commits as being linear, when merges introduce particular nonlinearities. The last of your questions ("How can I get commit 1 if I don't now it's id or commit message?") is: you can't, at least, not easily. You need to know *something* about the commit, in order to find it. There are a lot of tools for searching for things within the history (the set of commits) in a repository, though.

Comment: In this particular case, if the merge was done as a true merge *and* there have been no other merges since then, it may suffice to search backwards through the chain of commits to find the most recent merge (which is your "merge B into A" step). That merge commit has two parents and one of those two parents is likely to be the commit you want. Note that this depends on there being such a merge commit and your being able to find that merge commit.

Comment: your latest message answer my question in some way, so I'm marking your answer as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `git pull` to make sure your project is up-to-date with the repository. Now grab the commit id from before B was merged (we'll call it commit-id) and execute following commands:

```
$git branch my-new-branch                //This will create a new branch
$git branch -f my-new-branch commit-id   //This will point your local branch to the new commit
```

Comment: I need the commit before that commit

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. You can point your branch to any commit id and start working on that. If you provide more details I should be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Use cherry pick to bring changes in to current branch from another branch

Comment: Sorry this is not doable, there is a lot of changes 60k more or less